# I'm having trouble creating a language change function on renpy

Tags: python, translate, renpy

```
if renpy.language() == 'Japanese':
    define gui.text_font = "Fonts/mobog.ttc"
else:
    define gui.text_font = "Fonts/SourceHanSansLite.ttf"

if renpy.language() == 'Japanese':
    define gui.name_text_font = "Fonts/LightNovelPOPv2.otf"
else:
    define gui.name_text_font = "Fonts/Bazzi.ttf"

if renpy.language() == 'Japanese':
    define gui.interface_text_font = "Fonts/mobog.ttc"
else:
    define gui.interface_text_font = "Fonts/SourceHanSansLite.ttf"
```

Now this is a simple code that I made. And I already succeed to change the language of the game.
But, The japanese fonts wasn't apply on the game. what should I do for this trouble?

To solve that trouble I wrote this code

```
init python:
    style.create("text_korean", "default")
    style.text_korean.font = "Fonts/SourceHanSansLite.ttf"
    
    style.create("name_korean", "default")
    style.name_korean.font = "Fonts/Bazzi.ttf"
    
    style.create("interface_korean", "default")
    style.interface_korean.font = "Fonts/SourceHanSansLite.ttf"
```

```
screen text_screen(text=""):
    if renpy.language() == 'Japanese':
        text text style="text_japanese"
    else:
        text text style="text_korean"

screen name_text_screen(name=""):
    if renpy.language() == 'Japanese':
        text name style="name_japanese"
    else:
        text name style="name_korean"

screen interface_text_screen(interface_text=""):
    if renpy.language() == 'Japanese':
        text interface_text style="interface_japanese"
    else:
        text interface_text style="interface_korean"
```

But I got this Error.

the font keyword argument was not given a value

Comment: Provide some debugging details, please.